# update design attribute value dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, design-attributes

Is there a way to update a 'defaul' or manually entered design attribute value?

For example, 
[image]

component.cmp

```
 <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="someString" type="string" default="myString"/>

   <lightning:input aura:id="inputString" name="someString" label="change someString Attribute" value="{!v.someString}"/>

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="update someString attribute" onclick="{! c.handleClick }"/>

    <div>value should be:</div>
    <div>{!v.someString}</div>

</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        const newValue = component.find('inputString').get("v.value");
        component.set('v.someString', newValue);
    }
})
```

design file

```
<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="someString" description="want to update"/>
</design:component>
```

**Why all the hassle?**

> I implemented a set of templates a user can select from from a
>   lightning component, however, since all the logic is client side, the
>   state resets itself as soon as I refresh the page (to be expected), I
>   was wondering if, without apex, there was a way of changing the set
>   designed attribute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can dynamically change the options available in a design attribute -- at least picklist attributes -- by extending the VisualEditor.DynamicPickList class, but there isn't a way to change a value that was entered in Lightning App Builder. (You can manipulate the value once the component loads, but that won't change the value you'll see in the App Builder.)